# How to fix Internal Server Error 500

Tags: webserver

How to fix Internal Server Error 500

I have this not only on my php. also on my html files and folders.

The .htaccess file is empty

The issue is its happen after my server reboot.

However other accounts that reside on the same server still working, just that particular account.

what could had went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when one of your scripts has an error that is detected by the server. You should examine your server error log to see what caused the issue.